# mySql connections not being closed if a page is refreshed

Tags: mysql, web

If my web page is repeatedly refreshed before it finishes loading then the MySQL connections do not get closed and eventually it will throw a "Too many connections error" when it exceeds 150 processes.

I am not using a persistent connection and I have a `mysql_close()` at the end of the script even though I realize I do not need one as it will close.

How can I stop this from happening? I have never experienced this before on any previous servers I have used.

To stabilize my site I created a PHP script that every minute will kill old processes older than 120 seconds.  This is helping but not when I send more traffic to my site.

Comment: I have just uploaded all of my code to another server and the problem does not exist.  So I am now wondering if I have a faulty MySQL or a setting is not correct

Comment: I have just noticed that the mysql_connect() that was used in a codeigniter database class had a true as the new_link parameter.  I removed this and now all is ok :)

Answer (score 2):

This looks like the database simply can't handle all requests in time.

When a user visits your website, your script establishes a connection to the database server, **queries are executed**, results are fetched, displayed, the connection to the database server is closed.

If too many queries come in or the execution of a query takes too long the queue grows and grows till the server explodes.

You said you kill old processes - those are not old, they are simply not yet done, the requesting webserver process probably timed out already

Things you can do:

- optimize your database structure
- optimize your queries
- scale your hardware (scale up or, preferably, scale out)
- use caching
- optimize your server settings

The simplest and less time intensive, yet very effective improvement is probably output caching.

You simply safe the html output for hot sites and deliver it directly until the cache expires and the cache is refreshed.

Nginx can do this for you.

http://dangerousprototypes.com/docs/NGINX_reverse_proxy_in_front_of_Apache:_hardened,_high_performance_dedicated_server_setup

If you provide more info about your website architecture / and the software stack you are using I can get you more detailed help.

Comment: Thanks a great reply with some great advice.  I have just uploaded all of my code to another server and the problem does not exist.  So I am now wondering if I have a faulty MySQL or a setting is not correct

Comment: It is very unlikely a faulty server. The behaviour you describe above is nothing unusual with "high" traffic in an unoptimized environment. Might be possible to improve server settings like innodb buffer size, idle session timeout, max connections etc. This values and other optimization strongly depend on your hardware, amount of traffic, software stack, used programming language, used framework, current configuration, actual amount of traffic, db size etc etc. There are simply too many variables for further advice. I really recommend to look at nginx as a reverse proxy. simple and fast.

Answer (score 0):

The connection should be closed once you obtain the data.  Any webpage is stateless so it doesn't need a constant connection to the database, just when an autopostback happens then open the connection and close it again.  Store the data in a datatable container and then process it.  What language are you developing the web page in?